# Functions that can be represented by the Poisson integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $S = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : 0 \leq Re(z) \leq 1\}$. For $\theta \in (0, 1)$, let $\mu$ be the Poisson probability measure associated to $\theta$ for the strip $S$, that is $d\mu(z) = P_{\theta}(z) dz$, where

\begin{equation}
P_{\theta}(j + it) = \frac{e^{-\pi t}\sin \pi \theta}{\sin^2 \pi \theta + (\cos \pi\theta - e^{ij\pi - \pi t})^2}
\end{equation}

Let $f$ be an analytic function defined on $S$ with image in $c_{00}$ which is $L_1$ on $\delta S$ for $d\mu$ and which satisfies the Poisson integral representation

\begin{equation}
f(z_0) = \int\limits_{\delta S} f(z) dP_{z_0}(z)
\end{equation}

on $S$.

If $a$ and $b$ are positive real numbers, do the functions $\frac{f(z)}{a^z b^{1 - z}}$ and $a^{z - \theta}f(z)$ satisfy this Poisson integral representation?

If $f(\theta) = 0$, does the function $\frac{f(z)}{z - \theta}$, also satisfy the Poisson integral representation? (With the understanding that this function has value $f'(\theta)$ at $\theta$.)